# How to use comands within xltabular?

Tags: tables, xltabular

I need to use xltabular because I have long tables (which are longer than one page) with long texts. However xltabular brakes when I use commands inside (like \makecell, \multirow or \textcolor). For partial tables which fit in one page I can use tabularx and I don't have any problem to use these commands. When I add new rows to the table and transform it from tabularx to xltabular, it does not work. Is there any way to be able to use these commands within xltabular?

As example I show the same table (which fits in one page) only transforming it from tabularx to xltabular.

This works:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltxtable} % long tabularx
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.6\hsize}X} % For narrower columns of indicators
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X} % For narrower columns
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Characteristics of the indicators 'Total population' and 'Average household size' from DRC.}
\label{indicator:Numberofhouseholds}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{sSSSS}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Total population} \\ \hline
Measure \newline \makecell[r]{\textit{Base}} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering NSP} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering PR} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering MF} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering FW} \\
\hline
\textcolor{white}{.} \newline Million \newline \begin{flushright}\textit{61.8 (2009 base)}\end{flushright} & \makecell[c]{$\Downarrow$} \newline Total UK population decreases by 11\% as compared to 2010 values (UK: 55,002k). Assuming a growth rate of -0.1\% per annum from 2010 to 2025 and -0.4\% per annum from 2025 to 2050. & \makecell[c]{$\Leftrightarrow$} \newline Total UK population in 2050 reduces by 1\% as compared to 2010 values (UK: 61,184k). Assuming a growth rate of 0.1\% per annum from 2010 to 2025 and -0.1\% per annum from 2025 to 2050. & \makecell[c]{$\Leftrightarrow$} \newline Total UK population in 2050 reduces by 1\% as compared to 2010 values (UK: 61,184k). Assuming a growth rate of 0.1\% per annum from 2010 to 2025 and -0.1\% per annum from 2025 to 2050. & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$ | $\Uparrow$} \newline Total UK population increases by 3.0\% (UK: 63,680k). The ratio of rich to poor is 35:65 (22,288k:41,392k). Assuming a growth rate of 0.2\% per annum from 2010 to 2025 and 0.0\% per annum from 2025 to 2050.\\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Average household size} \\ \hline
\textcolor{white}{.} \newline People per household \newline \begin{flushright}\textit{2.4}\end{flushright} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} \newline Although population is ageing, strong social and environmental drivers mean co-housing and living with extended family or in multiple family units is commonplace. & \makecell[c]{$\Leftrightarrow$} \newline Trend towards smaller household sizes continues (exacerbated by ageing population). Core values of individualism mean people do not want to share accommodation. & \makecell[c]{$\Downarrow$} \newline Trend towards smaller household sizes continues (exacerbated by ageing population). Core values of individualism mean people do not want to share accommodation. & \makecell[c]{$\Downarrow$ | $\Uparrow$} \newline Average household size may increase for the poor out of necessity, and decrease for the rich out of choice.\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

But this doesn't:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltxtable} % long tabularx
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.6\hsize}X} % For narrower columns of indicators
\newcolumntype{S}{>{\hsize=1.1\hsize}X} % For narrower columns
\begin{document}


\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ssSSSS}
\caption{Characteristics of the indicators developed.\label{indicator:Numberofhouseholds}}\\
\small
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Total population} \\ \hline
Measure \newline \makecell[r]{\textit{Base}} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering NSP} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering PR} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering MF} & \multirow{2}{\linewidth}{\centering FW} \\
\hline
\textcolor{white}{.} \newline Million \newline \begin{flushright}\textit{61.8 (2009 base)}\end{flushright} & \makecell[c]{$\Downarrow$} \newline Total UK population decreases by 11\% as compared to 2010 values (UK: 55,002k). Assuming a growth rate of -0.1\% per annum from 2010 to 2025 and -0.4\% per annum from 2025 to 2050. & \makecell[c]{$\Leftrightarrow$} \newline Total UK population in 2050 reduces by 1\% as compared to 2010 values (UK: 61,184k). Assuming a growth rate of 0.1\% per annum from 2010 to 2025 and -0.1\% per annum from 2025 to 2050. & \makecell[c]{$\Leftrightarrow$} \newline Total UK population in 2050 reduces by 1\% as compared to 2010 values (UK: 61,184k). Assuming a growth rate of 0.1\% per annum from 2010 to 2025 and -0.1\% per annum from 2025 to 2050. & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$ | $\Uparrow$} \newline Total UK population increases by 3.0\% (UK: 63,680k). The ratio of rich to poor is 35:65 (22,288k:41,392k). Assuming a growth rate of 0.2\% per annum from 2010 to 2025 and 0.0\% per annum from 2025 to 2050.\\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Average household size} \\ \hline
\textcolor{white}{.} \newline People per household \newline \begin{flushright}\textit{2.4}\end{flushright} & \makecell[c]{$\Uparrow$} \newline Although population is ageing, strong social and environmental drivers mean co-housing and living with extended family or in multiple family units is commonplace. & \makecell[c]{$\Leftrightarrow$} \newline Trend towards smaller household sizes continues (exacerbated by ageing population). Core values of individualism mean people do not want to share accommodation. & \makecell[c]{$\Downarrow$} \newline Trend towards smaller household sizes continues (exacerbated by ageing population). Core values of individualism mean people do not want to share accommodation. & \makecell[c]{$\Downarrow$ | $\Uparrow$} \newline Average household size may increase for the poor out of necessity, and decrease for the rich out of choice.\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are some issues with your "does not work" example: First of all, the `xltabular` package is missing, second, `ltablex` is not needed iy you want to use `xltabular`, third  replace `\end{tabularx}` with `\end{xltabular}`.

Comment: By the way, there are at least three packages missing in your first working example: `makecell`,`multirow` and `xcolor`. These are also missing in your second, non-working example

Comment: Completely unrelated, but I would recommend to not call your new column type `S`. Since `siunitx` and `cellspace` also use `S` these packages might cause some interferences when used with your custom column type.

Comment: Regarding the error message itself: You can not use `\small` inside of `xltabular` as you did in your example code.

Comment: What ise `\textcolor{white}{.}` used for?

Comment: Also unrelated to the issue itself but regarding "long tables [...] with long texts": Please be aware that `xltabular` can not insert a pagebreak within a table row, just inbetween two table rows. (Pagebreaks can only occur where you user `\\ `)

Comment: @leandriis: Thanks! Sorry for the mess with packages missing in the example, I think they are not missing in my code :-P.

 - Is there any alternative for using small text size within `xltabular`?

 - `\textcolor{white}{.}` is to be able to write something which is not visible and use `\newline` to start the text in the second line so that it is aligned with the text from the other cells in the row (their first line contain an arrow). I guess there are more elegant ways to do that...
(I'll check the other comments when I'm in my work computer)

Comment: Do you want all to use the small font size for all entries in the table? Regarding the alignment: You can use one row for the arrows and a second, different row for "Million"  and the text in the other columns.

Comment: Also unrelated to the issue itself, but did you intentionally repeat some  texts in multiple cells? Probably using a multicolumn could help to avoid the repetition.

Comment: @leandriis: yes, in principle it would be better to use small font for all the entries in the table (as I couldn't really see the whole thing, I'm not yet sure). Oh, true, I could make an extra row :-S. That's actually very useful for the small table. Is there any way to tell 'xltabular' not to separate two rows when it breaks the page?

Comment: Ah, yes. The repetition of the text is intentional. It just happens that for the example I took, two columns show the same effect. :)

Comment: You can use `\\*` to prevent a pagebreak from happening between these two rows. Regarding the small text: You could use `>{\small}s` in order to decrease the font size to small in this specific column. Similarly, you can also use `>{\small\raggedright\arraybackslash}` in order to get left aligned text instead of justified text. This can help prevent large white spaces in narrow columns. If you only intend to use your newly defined column in this particular table, you can lso add the `\small` command to the `\newcolumntype` in the preamble.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. You were right, I forgot to add the packages in the preamble (as I created a new document to make trials) :-/ Sorry for all this. Although for me it has been mega-useful. Just 3 more questions: 1) for some reason the line "|" between the two arrows in the last column appears horizontal instead of vertical once the table is compiled "—". I can go around that using `\vert`, but do you understand why it happens? 2) For some reason the header appears again after the last row (this is in a new page with only the header and caption) 3) Should I delete the question?

Comment: It is strange, I can compile the example alone but when I copy paste it to the document where I want the table, it gives me an "undefined control sequence" error. I've double checked and all the packages are loaded. I tried to paste the example in overleaf and it also works fine. Any idea?

Comment: Regarding your question: 1) can be solved by adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. Currently I can't reproduce 2) and I don't see a reason to do 3). Which control sequence is undefined?

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
\LT@c@ption ...ndcsname }{#3}\LT@captionlistentry 
                                                  {#2}
l.122 \end{xltabular}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Comment: For 3), I thought it because the question is wrong, I was just not careful enough...

Comment: The undefined control sequence has something to do with the package `\usepackage{caption}`. I added it to my separate file for the table because the caption doesn't span the whole width of the table and then it also brakes with the same message. :S

Comment: Also, one small thing is that `\\*` does not work if it has a line afterwards `\\* \hline`

Comment: In case someone else reads until here, `\pagebreak` breaks the code (! Misplaced \omit. \multispan ->\omit \@multispan l.12 \end{tabularx}); one has to use `\noalign{\break}` instead.

Comment: And just for completeness, in order to make the caption span the width of the line, I had to add `\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}` before `\begin{xltabular}...`.

Comment: There's another thing, it complains that I have used the same label more than once, but I havent (overleaf gives the same complain).

Comment: @leandriis, any idea about the undefined control sequence problem that arises with the package caption? I cannot go around that, I need this package for other figures/tables

Comment: I can not reproduce this error when trying to combine `xltabular` and `caption`. (At least with the example document I was working on.) In order to find out what is causing the error, please prepare a MWE that allows others to reproduce the error you get.